# Is there a way to keep the reflection of the code implemented in _app.js of Next.js in a specific directory?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is there a way to keep the reflection of the code implemented in _app.js of Next.js in a specific directory?

Specifically, I want to reflect the code specified in _app.js only for the files under "Afolda" in the "pages / Afolda" directory.

Comment: can you give an example? Like specific, custom code you implement in _app.js? Or the entire component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Multiple zones](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/multi-zones) of Nextjs.

This allows you to specify different folder which nextjs can look for, could be like `/blog/**` and `/home/**`

There is one more way to override the way nextjs looks for pages, i.e by [disabling file-system routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server#disabling-file-system-routing) and adding your own custom server configuration.

Comment: Thank you for answering.   Try the multiple zones. It was helpful